# What parameters should I be using for the LogNormal and Normal Distribution in MATH.NET

Tags: c#, math.net

I've tried several combinations of Mathdotnet's LogNormal and Normal classes: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/LogNormal.

I seem to get a lot closer to the result I'm looking for using the mean and standard deviation as parameters.  However, I notice that when I use larger numbers, like numberOfMinutes my results do not deviate past the mean like they do with smaller numbers like numberOfDays do.  I know I'm not thinking about this right and could use some help.

Also, I'd like to use the geometric mean vs the mean but I didn't know what parameter to use for the variance given I couldn't pinpoint how to even use it for the mean.

Finally, I hope the answer to this also answers the same issue I'm having with the Normal distribution.

```
List<double> numberOfDays = new List<double> { 10, 12, 18, 30 };

double mean = numberOfDays.Mean();  // 17.5
double geometricMean = numberOfDays.GeometricMean(); // 15.954
double variance = numberOfDays.Variance();  // 81
double standardDeviation = numberOfDays.StandardDeviation(); // 9
// Do I need a Geometric Standard Deviation or Variance

double numberOfDaysSampleMV = LogNormal.WithMeanVariance(mean, variance).Sample();   // One example sample yielded 40.23                
double numberOfDaysSampleMSD = LogNormal.WithMeanVariance(mean, standardDeviation).Sample(); // One example sample yielded 17.33
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confused about the parameters required. Using conventional notation, you have set X which you believe is LogNormal:

```
 X = { 10, 12, 18, 30 }
mean: m = 17.5
standard deviation: sd = 9
```

from this you derive set Y which is Normal:

```
Y = {2.30,2.48,2.89,3.4}
mean: mu = 2.77
standard deviation: sigma = 0.487
```

Note that mu and sigma are computed from Y, not X.  To create sample of the LogNormal data, you use mu and sigma, not m and sd.

```
double[] sample = new double[100];
 LogNormal.Samples(sample, mu, sigma);
```

This is consistent with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) on the LogNormal distribution. The Numerics documentation is not clear.

Here is my test program which might be useful:

```
            List<double> X = new List<double> { 10, 12, 18, 30 };  // assume to be LogNormal
            double m = X.Mean();               // mean of log normal values = 17.5
            double sd = X.StandardDeviation(); // standard deviation of log normal values = 9

            List<double> Y = new List<double> { };
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Y.Add(Math.Log(X[i]));
            }
            // Y = {2.30,2.48,2.89,3.4}

            double mu = Y.Mean();                 // mean of normal values = 2.77
            double sigma = Y.StandardDeviation(); // standard deviation of normal values = 0.487

            double[] sample = new double[100];
            LogNormal.Samples(sample, mu, sigma);          // get sample    
            double sample_m = sample.Mean();               // 17.93, approximates m
            double sample_sd = sample.StandardDeviation(); // 8.98, approximates sd

            sample = new double[100];
            Normal.Samples(sample, mu, sigma);                // get sample    
            double sample_mu = sample.Mean();                 //2.77, approximates mu
            double sample_sigma = sample.StandardDeviation(); //0.517 approximates sigma
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your test program above my samples came out like this.

[Using LogNormal(mu, sigma)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIBvK.png)

I'm ultimately concerned about the values greater than 30 and less than 10.

However, by trail and error [accidentally], when I use the following method to get the samples using the original m and sd variable in your test program I get the results I'm looking for.  I do not want to go forward with something I accidentally did.

```
sample = new double[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sample[i] = LogNormal.WithMeanVariance(m, sd).Sample();
}
```

[Using LogNormal.WithMeanVariance(m, sd)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPakq.png)

My values are consistently between the Min and Max and concentrated around the Mean.

Answer (score 0):

1. My example shows pretty clearly how to get a LogNormal sample that has the mean and standard deviation of the original data.
2. The min/max of 10/30 is unrealistic if you are going create your samples based on the mean and standard deviation of the sample. Suppose you took of random sample of the weights of 4 people out of a population of 1000 people. Would you expect your sample to include both the lightest and heaviest of the population?
3. LogNormal.WithMeanVariance(m, sd) is wrong. The units are wrong. It's expecting a variance would have the units of ln(days)^2 while sd has units of days.
4. I suggest you a) use LogNormal(mu,sigma) and discard any values that are outside your min/max range or b) use LogNormal(mu,c*sigma) for some value of c less than one to reduce the variance enough that all the values are in your min/max range. The choice depends on the nature of your project.
5. The Wikipedia entry on the LogNormal distribution has formulas for computing mu and sigma from m and sd which might be better than calculating from the Y data.

Comment: I have thought about eliminating the values not in the min max as bullet number 4 states.  I have to have 1000 samples, would you recommend I loop through the samples until I get 1000 within my range.  The nature of the project is that 10 and 30 are the true min and max of the samples I want to produce.  I’ve used the triangular and beta distribution with success and I’m trying to mirror the results with the lognormal and normal distributions.

Comment: Also, you peaked my curiosity with the c * sigma option in bullet 4.  Is there a calculated value I could use for c to make sure the values will fall in the min max and create the kind of curve I’ve shown I want to produce.  I put four values in my example but the fact of the matter is that there will always only be three (three point estimate)to take into consideration for the mu and sigma.

Comment: Choose c so that c × the largest value = 30.

Comment: Could you provide an example for the initial scenario?

Comment: With the LogNormal distribution, you don't have an upper bound on the samples, but you can find a limit which you are unlikely to exceed. On your LogNormal graph, the maximum is 86. We can calculate that 86 is about 7.55 standard deviations above the mean: (86-m)/sd = (86-18)/9 = 7.55 . So you want to pick a value for the sd such that  the mean + 7.55 * sd = 30. So sd = (30-18)/7.55 = 1.6. So you want  LogNormal.Samples(sample, 18, 1.6) If you still get some values outside your min/max range, reduce the 1.6 a bit.